# Team Foundation Server 2018 API Build Definition Error

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a new build definition through REST API using Powershell 5.1.

My script consist of some files.
In my script I have this:

File 1:

```
 $newDefinitionUrl = "http://tfs:8080/tfs/collection/project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version={2}" -f $CollectionUrl,$TeamProjectName,$BuildApiVersion
        $method = "POST"
        $headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/json"} 
        $body=ConvertTo-Json $template -Depth 20 -Compress  

    #[ERROR 1 - line 80] 
    Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $credentials -Uri $newDefinitionUrl -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body))
```

File 2:

```
$templateName = "$bdType $systemTecnology"
$buildDefinitionName = Get-GloboBuildDefinitionName -System $System -BranchName $BranchName -Type $Type

 #[Error 2 - Line 115]
$newDef = New-BuildDefinition -CollectionUrl $Tfs.Uri.AbsoluteUri -TeamProjectName $TeamProjectName -TemplateName $templateName  -BuildDefinitionName $buildDefinitionName -TemplateTeamProjectName $TeamProjectBuildTemplate -OverwriteParameters $parameters
```

File 3:

```
Write-Output "`t-> Criando branch para o $workitemTitle no SourceControl apartir do Release..." -OutVariable +MSGS
        New-TFVCBrach -Tfs $Tfs -SourcePath "$/$TeamProjectName/$System/$branchOrigin" -DestinationPath "$/$TeamProjectName/$System/$branchFolder/$workitemTitle" -ErrorVariable +MSGS | Out-String | Write-Verbose

        Write-Output "`t-> Concedendo permissão ao time ""[$TeamProjectName]\$System"" no branch..." -OutVariable +MSGS
        Get-Content $GloboTFSSetupTemplateFolderPath"\PermissionsFolders.txt" | Set-BranchPermisisons -CollectionUrl $CollectionUrl -TeamProjectName $TeamProjectName -System $System -BranchRelativePath "$branchFolder/$workitemTitle" -Group "[$TeamProjectName]\$System" -ErrorVariable +MSGS | Out-String | Write-Verbose

        Write-Output "`t-> Criando build definition de ""$buildType"" para o ""$WorkItemType""..." -OutVariable +MSGS

#[Error 3 - Line 99]            
New-GloboBuildDefinition -Tfs $Tfs -TeamProjectName $TeamProjectName -System $System -Type $buildType -BranchName $workitemTitle -ErrorVariable +MSGS | Out-String | Write-Verbose
```

When I try to run the script I get 3 errors which I have marked with #[Error 1/2/3 - Line x] for easy identification here.

This are the errors:

[image]

In my TFS 2015 this scripts worked.
But now in TFS 2018 I am getting this errors.

Can anyone help me with this?

In addition I also get some more errors:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Cannot index into a null array. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot index into a null array. at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.b__0() at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeUsingCmdlet(Cmdlet contextCmdlet, Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Object[] args) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand.ProcessRecord() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
Cannot index into a null array.
Cannot index into a null array.
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Cannot index into a null array. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot index into a null array. at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.b__0() at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeUsingCmdlet(Cmdlet contextCmdlet, Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Object[] args) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand.ProcessRecord() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
Cannot index into a null array.
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The collection must contain at least one element.\r\nParameter name: PathFilters","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0} ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input) at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The collection must contain at least one element.\r\nParameter name: PathFilters","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

EDIT1: I've been trying to figure this out and I've found this:
[TFS2015 REST API Build definition update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378702/tfs2015-rest-api-build-definition-update)

However I don't know how to fix my errors.
I've tried changing my code -Depth but still I am getting errors.
Please Help.

Comment: You mean in line 80 right? How should I leave it than?

Comment: Can you right it here how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I have never had to do the Text encoding to get this to work.  I usually just pass the json to the Invoke-RestMethod request.  I tried editing one of my known good functions to add the encoding and it seems to give similar errors.  I'd try adjusting your code to this:

```
$newDefinitionUrl = "http://tfs:8080/tfs/collection/project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version={2}" -f $CollectionUrl,$TeamProjectName,$BuildApiVersion
    $method = "POST"
    $headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/json"} 
    $body=ConvertTo-Json $template -Depth 20 -Compress  

#[ERROR 1 - line 80] 
Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $credentials -Uri $newDefinitionUrl -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that tomorrow and than I'll reply. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've tried that but now I get a different error. I'll post here in the answer.

Comment: I've tried your solution but I am still getting errors. The some errors as it seems. Any ideas?